Modal de react con ant design no se actualiza
Tengo un proyecto con react donde renderizo una lista donde cada elemento tiene un boton para editar este, cargar la info actual como default para despues editarla y enviarla, al abrir el modal del primer elemento todo funciona pero con los modals de todos los elementos que abra despues se muestra como default la informacion del primer elemento del cual abri el modal. Renderizo los elementos con el siguiente metodo map:
{showList.map((item) => (
    <div className="listItem" key={item.id}>
        <div className="info">
            <h1>{item.name}</h1>
            <h2>{item.id}</h2>
        </div>

        <div className="buttons">
            <Tooltip title='Editar'>
                <Button shape="circle" type="primary" icon={<EditOutlined />} size="large" onClick={() => {setSelectedEmploye(item); setEditEmploye(true)}}/>
            </Tooltip>
            <Tooltip title='Borrar'>
                <Button shape="circle" variant="solid" color="danger" icon={<DeleteOutlined />} onClick={() => {setSelectedEmploye(item); setDeleteEMploye(true)}} size="large"/>
            </Tooltip>
        </div>
    </div>
))}

Los modals los llamo desde el mismo archivo de la siguiente manera:
<NewUserModal title='Agregar empleado' open={newEmploye} onCancel={() => setNewEmploye(false)} client={false} cargoControl={setCargo} onOk={submitNewEmploye}/>
<DeleteModal open={deleteEmploye} onCancel={() => setDeleteEMploye(false) }/>
<EditUserModal open={editEmploye} onCancel={() => setEditEmploye(false)} info={selectedEmploye} title='Editar Empleado' client={false}/>

y en el archivo desde donde se exportan es este:
export const EditUserModal = ({title, open, onCancel, cargoControlEdited, onOk, info, client }) => {
    return(
        <Modal title={title} open={open} onCancel={onCancel} onOk={onOk}>
                <Form>
                    <Form.Item name="userId">
                        <Input placeholder="Cedula" defaultValue={info.id} disabled={true}></Input>
                    </Form.Item>
                    <Form.Item name="userName">
                        <Input placeholder="Nombre" defaultValue={info.name} disabled={true}></Input>
                    </Form.Item>
                    <Form.Item name="userEmail" rules={[{type: "email", message: 'Por favor ingrese un correo valido'}]}>
                        <Input placeholder="Correo electronico" defaultValue={info.email}></Input>
                    </Form.Item>
                    <Form.Item name="userAddress">
                        <Input placeholder="Direccion" defaultValue={info.address}></Input>
                    </Form.Item>
                    <Form.Item name="userPhone">
                        <Input placeholder="Telefono" defaultValue={info.phone}></Input>
                    </Form.Item>
                    <Form.Item name="userPassword">
                        <Input.Password placeholder="Contraseña" disabled={client} ></Input.Password>
                    </Form.Item>
                    <Form.Item label='Cargo'>
                        <Select
                        disabled={client}
                        defaultValue={info.type}
                        onChange={(e) => cargoControlEdited(e)}
                        options={[
                            {value: 0, label: 'Empleado'},
                            {value: 1, label: 'Gerente'}
                        ]}
                        />
                    </Form.Item>
                </Form>
            </Modal>
    )
}


Prueba añadiendo la propiedad destroyOnClose al Modal. Por ejemplo: <Modal {...props} destroyOnClose> ... </Modal>. Comenta el resultado.

si, la propiedad de destroyOnClose resolvio el problema
